# Manual Texlive installation: Missing links and missing binaries, e.g. pdfnup

Tags: texlive, ubuntu

I installed TexLive manually (net install) following the instructions found on the German Ubuntuusers page (https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/TeX_Live/#Manuell).

During installation, I selected all collections I need, including "collection-binextra".

1. While some binaries are referenceded in PATH, like pdflatex, others are not, e.g. pdfjam
   `/usr/local/bin/pdflatex -> /usr/local/texlive/2019/bin/x86_64-linux/pdflatex`
   `/usr/local/texlive/2019/bin/x86_64-linux/pdfjam`

   Do I have to link all binaries myself, or is there a script/mechanism to link all the binaries that are linked in the ubuntu repo install?
2. Some binaries present in a ubuntu repo install of TL are missing in the manual installation, e.g. pdfnup.
   Anyone know why they are missing? And how to install them correctly?

(Btw I needed the manual installation as some xetex requirements found in the ubuntu packages were too old)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I think I found all the answers I need:

1. `tl-install` seems to link some binaries explicitely, but there is no general rule for binaries to be linked.
   Furthermore, I ask myself why they do not just add the binaries folder to `PATH` for that purpose.
2. TL 2019 is shipped with pdfjam 3.03, which according to https://ctan.org/tex-archive/support/pdfjam is no longer shipped with the additional scripts like pdfnup, pdfjoin, ...

Comment: Those scripts are now at this repo: https://github.com/rrthomas/pdfjam-extras